# Как можно взять координаты GPS и отобразить на GMaps?

Tags: java, android, gps

## Нужно взять координаты GPS и отобразить его на карте.Использую библиотеку

`compile 'com.github.delight-im:Android-SimpleLocation:v1.0.1'`

```
public class MyLocation extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SimpleLocation location;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_location);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        location = new SimpleLocation(MyLocation.this);
        final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        final LatLng llng = new LatLng(longitude,latitude);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(llng)
                        .title("Мое местонахождение"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(llng));
            }});
}
}
```

Из-за того что метка на карте появляется только в одном месте подумал может это инет гонит.И повесил слушатель на одну кнопку.Такой же код, просто не в `onCreate`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final double latd = location.getLatitude();
                final double longtd = location.getLongitude();
                final LatLng llll = new LatLng(latd,longtd);
                Log.e("latd",latd+"");
                Log.e("longtd",longtd+"");
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(llll)
                                .title("Мечит"));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(llll));
                    }});
            }
        });
```

Все равно ничего не работает и никаких ошибок..

Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Какое ожидаемое поведение и какое поведение сейчас?